# Webpage background image won't load

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following css to define my background:

```
body
{
    background-image: url('background.png');
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Veranda, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

The image `background.png` is stored in the root directory, but whenever I refresh the webpage, the background remains white. MY instructor currently has a copy of my files and is attempting to figure it out himself, though the problem wasn't obvious to him at a cursory glance. My full html and css are as follows:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content = "text/html charset = utf-8" />
<link rel = stylesheet href = "style.css" type = "text/css" media = screen>
<title>
Title
</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id = "wrapper">
    <div id = "leftsidebar">
        <h3> Navigation </h3>
    </div>

    <div id = "content">
        <h1> Heading 1 </h1>
        <h2> Heading 2 </h2>

        <p align = "justify"> Paragraph 1.</p>

        <p align = "justify"> Paragraph 2 </p>

        <p align = "justify"> Paragraph 3 </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
<style type = "text/css">
<!--
body
{
    background-image: url('background.png');
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Veranda, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div#wrapper
{
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: thin solid #000000;
}

div#header
{
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: centre;
}

div#leftsidebar
{
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    float: left;
}

div#content
{
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    padding: 10px;
}

div#footer
{
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-top: thin solid #000000;
}
-->
</style>
```

Comment: is your background.png also in the root directory? I would generally don't recommend using relative paths here in that manner ( start with / (root) ). Also you can use firebug to see if the img gets load at all ... also, whats with the weird white spaces between attributes and values in the link element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS files are not supposed to contain

```
<style type = "text/css">
<!--
```

I assume that leads to an error parsing the first CSS block (the `body` one).

Answer (score 1):

html is not allowed in you style.css

You need to remove the `<style type = "text/css">`, the html comment tag `<!--` and obviously the closing tags for each.

You also dont need the ' ' around the background url, it can be written like this.

```
background-image: url(background.png);
```

Make those changes, and assuming background.png is in the correct directory it will work.